# iTextSharp throws an exception when it reads a PDF created with an empty signature container (to embed the received signature from the client)

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-reader

Help please. I'm trying to get a "deferred" digital signature and embed it in a PDF document. On the server (.net core 3.1) I create a test pdf and add an empty container for the signature. To do this, I use the **iTextSharp** package (version 5.5.13.3):

```
    public static byte[] GetPdfBytesToSign(byte[] unsignedPdf, string signatureFieldName)
    {
        //unsignedPdf - source PDF
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdf))
        {
            //looking for existing signatures
            int existingSignaturesNumber = reader.AcroFields.GetSignatureNames().Count;
            using (MemoryStream tempPdf = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //add an empty container for a new signature
                using (PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, tempPdf, '\0', null, true))
                {
                    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = st.SignatureAppearance;
                    appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(205, 700, 390, 800), reader.NumberOfPages,
                        //set the name of the field, it will be needed later to insert a signature
                        $"{signatureFieldName}{existingSignaturesNumber + 1}");
                    ExternalBlankSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
                    MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, BufferSize);
                    //get a stream that contains the sequence we want to sign
                    using (Stream contentStream = appearance.GetRangeStream())
                    {
                        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                        contentStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                        byte[] bytesToSign = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        return bytesToSign;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the problem!!! For some reason, iText can't read the PDF it created with an empty signature container (to embed the received signature from the client).

```
        public static byte[] GetSignedPdf(byte[] unsignedPdfWithContainer, byte[] signature)
    {
        using var pdfReader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdfWithContainer);//<--throwing an exception here
        using var output = new MemoryStream();

        var external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signature);
        MakeSignature.SignDeferred(pdfReader, SignatureFieldName, output, external);
        return output.ToArray();

    }
```

I am getting the following exception:
**iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: "Unexpected '>>' at file pointer 1432"**

Test(source) pdf is created like this:

```
        public static byte[] CreatePdf()
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
            document.Close();
            writer.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does `GetSignedPdf` get the `unsignedPdfWithContainer` from? In `GetPdfBytesToSign` you do not keep the prepared file which is in `tempPdf`.

Comment: @mkl Thanks! Actually, that was the problem! Now the program works, but the signature is not valid :( 
Cause: wrong hash value

Comment: I don't know how exactly you executed the fix. Because the code above does return the data to sign while the data you need to open in the `PdfReader` later on is the content of `tempPdf`. Thus, you need the contents of both memory streams in `GetPdfBytesToSign`...

Comment: @mkl Thanks, I saved the `tempPdf` stream and passed it and the received signature from the client to the `GetSignedPdf` method, after which the signature was added to the test pdf document, but it is not valid. However, that's another question.